# i want to create a variable that holds date in sequence

Tags: ssis

i want to create a variable in SSIS that contains a date. The format is

> "/vaftp1/NewFile/data/2014-06-08 02;01;38 (Full).zip" ,
>   "/vaftp1/NewFile/data/2014-07-08 02;01;38 (Full).zip",
>   "/vaftp1/NewFile/data/2014-08-08 02;00;42 (Full).zip"

this file will dump on ftp site every day and I want to unzip it. so my question is I created a variable

> "/vaftp1/NewFile/data/"+ (DT_WSTR, 20) (DT_DBDATE)
>   GETDATE()+?????????????()+""(full)"+".zip"

but its not working.i don't know want to ignore ??????? . all i want is to get the date + anything(means the time)+(full)+.zip like for word we say (*.txt)to get any thing end by .txt so please help me

Comment: Can you reformat this question to be a little friendlier to read?  There are markup tools to do this.

Comment: it is not working .. it is giving me this kind of errer 0xC0029183 at FTP Task, FTP Task: File represented by "User::FTPInput" does not exis

Comment: it is not working .. it is giving me this kind of error "0xC0029183 at FTP Task, FTP Task: File represented by "User::FTPInput" does not exits" but I give it the hole date and time it works

Comment: How are you giving whole date and time... and are you giving the current date and current time?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example strings and your sample expression. Give this a try -

> "//vaftp1//NewFile//data//"+ SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR, 50) (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)
>   GETDATE(), 1, 19)+" (full)"+".zip"